# How to capture image in ellipse form in OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, face-detection, image-capture

Can someone please guide me? I am trying to detect face and then capture image in the ellipse form using OpenCV. The following is an example of how it looks like when I run my python script.

[image]

At the moment, I am just detecting face and have created this fixed frame. I also managed to find the solution for of how to do it in rectangle form but I need to capture image in ellipse form. Can someone please help me with? Also, this is my code:

```
import cv2
import sys
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = video_capture.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(
        gray,
        scaleFactor=1.1,
        minNeighbors=25,
        minSize=(30, 30),
        flags=cv2.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE
    )

    # Draw a rectangle around the faces
    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
    
        #320 horizontal position, 250 vertical position, 80 horizontal size, 120 vertical size
        #0 angle, 0 startangle, 360 endangle
        #(0, 255, 0) color, 2 thickness
    
        startAngle = 0
        endAngle = 10
        for z in range(20):
            cv2.ellipse(frame, (320, 250), (80, 120), 0, startAngle, endAngle, (255, 255, 255), 2)
            startAngle = startAngle+20
            endAngle = endAngle+20
    
        #Centered Vertical Dashed Line
        xCord = 320
        yCord = 400
        for z in range(12):
            cv2.line(frame, (xCord, yCord), (xCord, yCord-20), (255, 255, 255), 2)
            yCord = yCord-25

        #Upper Horizontal Dashed Line
        xCord = 160
        yCord = 130
        for z in range(13):
            cv2.line(frame, (xCord, yCord), (xCord+20, yCord), (255, 255, 255), 2)
            xCord = xCord+25
    
        #Lower Horizontal Dashed Line
        xCord = 160
        yCord = 370
        for z in range(13):
            cv2.line(frame, (xCord, yCord), (xCord+20, yCord), (255, 255, 255), 2)
            xCord = xCord+25
    
        cv2.putText(frame, 'Head', (330, 120), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX , 0.5, (255, 255, 255), 2) 
        cv2.putText(frame, 'Chin', (330, 390), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX , 0.5, (255, 255, 255), 2) 

        # Display the resulting frame
        cv2.imshow('Video', frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('c'):
        crop_img = frame[y-50: y+h+10, x: x+w] # Crop from x, y, w, h -> 100, 200, 300, 400, y-50 is to include head in the picture too y+h+10 is to include chin.
            cv2.imwrite("media/faces/face.jpg", crop_img)

# When everything is done, release the capture
video_capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: It is not exactly clear what you mean by 'capture image in ellipse' mean. In solutions see what my take is on what you mean. Let me know if that's not what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: I have edited the code so that it's a stand alone code for image containing one single face.

```
faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

rgb = cv2.imread('/path/to/your/faceImage.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(rgb, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(
    gray,
    scaleFactor=1.1,
    minNeighbors=25,
    minSize=(30, 30),
    flags=cv2.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE
)

x,y,w,h = faces[0] # Working with image with only one face
imh,imw = gray.shape

center_x, center_y = int(x+w/2), int(y+h/2)

mask = np.zeros((imh,imw),np.uint8)
cv2.ellipse(mask, (center_x, center_y), (int(w/2), int(h/2)), 0, 0, 360, 255, cv2.FILLED)
rgb[mask == 0] = 255
plt.imshow(rgb[y:y+h, x:x+w])
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but it doesn't show anything on executing nor it gives any error.

Comment: Check if this stand alone code does what you are looking for. If so, adjust your code by cut-pasting relevant lines from it.

Comment: It worked. Just needed to add plt.show() at the end of it and need to edit it somewhat according to my code. Thanks so much.